# incremental value using setInterval in react broken

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function App() {
  const [tick, setTick] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setTick(tick + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, [tick]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{tick}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

it turned out to be incrementing more than 1 per second, it worked at the beginning and it started to messed up later. See demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-kepler-vvzr7

Comment: You can use this https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 3):

Cause every time you update the `tick`, the effect triggers and starts another timer... The effect shall not depend on `tick`:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let id = setInterval(() => {
      setTick(tick => tick + 1); // No dependency anymore
    }, 1000);

    // This has nothing todo with your problem, but I encourage you to correctly clean up effects:
    return () => clearInterval(id);
 }, []); // <<
```

Comment: how to stop the increment it after 5 seconds?

Comment: @jennifer store the `id` inside a `useRef()` outside of the effect.

Comment: can't it be just using setTimeout like so? https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-architecture-fuwcw

Answer (score 0):

I would use class-component for your case

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { tick: 0 };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      const newTick = this.state.tick + 1;
      this.setState({ tick: newTick });
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>{this.state.tick}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

register the interval in `componentDidMount` method , to unregister use `componentWillUnmount` method

checkout [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-bassi-xyzkm)